# Fixing Permute Output

Tags: php, permutation

**Hey there** I've made a recursive permutation function for class, but I output is less than favorable.
http://codepad.org/DOaMP9oc

```
function permute($arr) {
    $out = array();
    if (count($arr) > 1) {
        $i = 0;
        foreach($arr as $r => $c) {
            $n = $arr;
            unset($n[$r]);
            $out[$c] = permute($n);
        }
    }
    else
        return array_shift($arr);
    return $out;
}
```

***If input is `array(1,2,3,4,5)`, Output is:***

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [4] => 5
                            [5] => 4
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [3] => 5
                            [5] => 3
                        )

                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [3] => 4
                            [4] => 3
                        )

                )
ETC......................
```

***This is all Correct***, you can read it like this key.key.key.key.value or `12345`,`12354`,`12435`

Currently, to convert this output to something readable, I'm using this ugly block of code:
http://codepad.org/qyWcRBCl

```
foreach($out as $k => $a) 
    foreach($a as $l => $b) 
        foreach ($b as $m => $c) 
            foreach ($c as $n => $d) 
                echo $k.$l.$m.$n.$d.'<br>';
```

## How can I alter my function to eliminate the `foreach` stack and output in a similar format from `permute()`.

Comment: What's "more readable" than each number on a new line?

Comment: The foreach method is inefficient, and can only sets of 5 letters. I want to eliminate the foreach and output in a readable format from `permute()`.

Comment: `in case my teacher has a hard time reading it.` Stack is not the place for answers to homework

Comment: This is not specifically for homework, it's to teach me a way of outputting differently that I can't seem to figure out. The homework is completely finished, this will pass no problem.

Comment: However, you would be correct if my assignment was to output in a specific manner, which it isn't.

Comment: @misterkoz I'd really like to do it within the function if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opted to use the following function:

```
function showPerms($a,$i='') {
    if (is_array($a))
        foreach($a as $k => $v) 
            showPerms($v,$i.$k);
    else 
        echo $i.$a."\n";
}
```

However, I'd still like to do this in a singular recursive function.

Answer (score 1):

**My solution is to work on strings:**

```
function permute($string) {
    if (strlen($string)<2) {
        return array($string);
    }

    $permutations = array();

    // Copy everything but the first character of the string.
    $copy = substr($string, 1);

    foreach (permute($copy) as $permutation) {
        $length = strlen($permutation);

        // Insert the first character of the original string.
        for ($i=0; $i<=$length; $i++) {
            $permutations[] = substr($permutation, 0, $i) . $string[0] . substr($permutation, $i);
        }
    }

    sort($permutations);

    return $permutations;
}

header('Content-type:text/plain');
print_r(permute('12345'));
```

You already have a working implementation so I have no qualms in giving that to you.  Note that the array is not created in order, so I simply sort it at the end.  Also note that this only works on things that you intend to have the value of 1 character, so doing a permutation of car names would not work.

---

Even if you don't like this answer, I suggest that you use a type-hint for array:

```
function permute(array $arr) {
```

This will enforce that you pass an array into it.

Comment: Unfortunately, the assignment was specific to using array's and not strings.

Comment: Thank you for that PS, I forgot about that ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
function display_permutation($array){
 if(is_array($array)){
   foreach($array as $key => $val){
     echo $key;
 display_permutation($val);
   }
 }else{
echo $array;
 }
}
```

Comment: I opted for a similar solution, the only problem is that that doesn't output accurately, it outputs a single string. Also I'd like to combine functions.

Comment: if you are indenting by the depth try including a depth field in the recursive method, and echo tab's/greater than's to that dept on a per line basis.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my permutation function and we can display results in simple way

```
class Permute {
    public $results = Array();
    public function __construct(array $array) {
        $this->_permute($array);
    }

    private function _permute(array $orig, array $perm = Array()) {
        if(!count($orig)) {
            $this->results[] = $perm;
            return null;
        }
        $count = count($orig);
        for($i = 0; $i < $count; ++$i) {
            $orig2 = $orig;
            unset($orig2[$i]);
            $orig2 = array_values($orig2);
            $perm2 = $perm;
            $perm2[] = $orig[$i];
            $this->_permute($orig2, $perm2);
        }
    }
}


$arr = Array(1,2,3,4,5);
$permute = new Permute($arr);

foreach($permute->results as $result) {
    echo join('', $result).'<br>';
}
```